# Dead space in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, swift, xcode6

The print screen I'm annexing was taken from an iPhone 4S. What you can see is a UITableView with a custom header view. What I don't understand is, what is that dead space on top? How can I remove it?

[image]

Comment: Isn't that juste the first cell ?

Comment: The grey area is the navigationbar.

Comment: There are many possibilities for that, Can you please paste the table view methods here for giving you the exact solution. Do mention is that made from story board or XIB ?

Comment: I just created it with storyboard, and didn't really add anything to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- 
edit: To remove navigationbar from your UITableViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

--

If your UITableViewController is `embedded in a Navigation Controller`, you will automatically get a navigationbar:
[image: navigationcontroller]

To fill the whole screen `without navigation bar`, make sure it is not embedded in a Navigation Controller:

[image: not embedded]

Comment: You can have for example 2 views that cover the fullscreen. Both connected via IBOutlet but to different properties (maybe named: gameView and startView). In code you can now say `self.startView.hidden = YES;` and `self.gameView.hidden = NO;` Or did you meant to ask how to perform Segues (go to other scenes in storyboard) without a Navigation bar?

Comment: Hm. Besides this navbar thing, what's the practical difference?

Comment: Well if you have one Scene (ViewController) that has 10 fullscreen views on it and all the code is in the same .M file, then I suggest using more scenes with their own .h .m files. But if you are making a simple app that has 2 or 3 views, you can use one ViewController so you don't have to pass values to other ViewControllers when performing segues.

Answer (score 2):

Your Gray Area is Navigation Bar.

Please check it is plain or grouped table.

Because in Grouped(Section) table view, it'll have space for section.

[image]

Other scenario, You have set custom Header view. But If your Navigation Controller is in **Transcluent** mode, then header will be under Navigation Bar.

So, Table automatically goes up.

[image]

Hopefully, it'll help you to identify your problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a UINavigationController showing. 
If you don't need it, set

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple solution

keep height of header/footer at your conviniency

code :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 10;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 10;
}
```